# Laravel Wrong Pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

I am using Laravel.
I wrote a function to show all users articles. In controller:

```
public function user($id)
{
    $tricks = Trick::where('author',$id)->orderBy('date','desc')->orderBy('id','desc')->where('publish',1)->paginate(5);
    $metaTitle = 'Articles'. MyVB::username($id);
    return View::make('list.index')->with('items',$tricks)->with('metaTitle',$metaTitle);
}
```

and in Routes:

```
   Route::get('user/{id}',array('uses'=>'TrickController@user','as'=>'user'));
```

I checked my site by this link for example:

```
http://www.example.com/user/3
```

and everything was fine and pagination worked like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/3?page=2
http://www.example.com/user/3?page=3
```

then accidentally checked another user, for example:

```
http://www.example.com/user/6701
```

then I realized page links are wrong!:

```
http://www.example.com/user/6702
http://www.example.com/user/6703 and...
```

instead of this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/6701?page=2
http://www.example.com/user/6701?page=3
```

I checked another users, some of them are correct and some of them are wrong.
I am confused now because I cant find any logic about this.

this is my pagination.blade.php in views:

```
<?php
$links = $items->links();
$patterns = array();
$patterns[] = '/'.$items->getCurrentPage().'\?page=/';
$replacements = array();
$replacements[] = '';
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $links); 
?>
```

Any ideas about this problem?

Comment: check if the number of articles leads to another page or not ;)

Comment: @user3786134 sorry I did not get your point, can you explain more?